# jquery .load not loading immediately after loading data

Tags: php, jquery

I was wondering if this was making an asynchronous request...write now Im using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       var ktitle = $('.hiddentwo').text();
       $('div#tab2').load('morefour.php?title=' + encodeURIComponent(ktitle));
    });  
</script>
```

what Im doing though is adding text in the first, into the database, on the current php file (addtext.php). Im passing the Id of the current document to the morefour.php and that is loading the added text on the second tab...the thing is, Im having to refresh to see the content again. Im running on localhost btw.

For more clarity, Im running another jquery script that on clicks, retrieves this data to send it to a php file to enter into a database

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).siblings().outerHTML();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "tosqltwo.php",
        data: {
            content: content
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){   //shorthand of $(document).ready
 $('div#tab2').html($.ajax({
      type: "GET", //if you are doin $_GET['title'] in morefour.php
      url: "morefour.php",
      data : {title:ktitle},
      dataType: 'html', //i am not sure about this part
      async: false
     }).responseText)
});
```

or you can try

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({ 
  url : 'morefour.php',
  data : {title:ktitle},
  type:'GET',
  dataType:'html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('div#tab2').html(data);
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function with **async** to **false**.

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url : 'morefour.php',
  data : 'title=' + encodeURIComponent(ktitle),
  success: function(data) {
    $('div#tab2').html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry someone informed me that .load was async.

Comment: im still having to refresh though to see the newly added content

Comment: Strange, it should not happen, at what event you are binding this? at the click of tab?